# Send json data as url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I m trying to pass json data

```
var  data = JSON.parse("[" + detail + "]"))
or the results of var detail = $('#grid-table').getCell(rowid, '11') 
results as parameters of the url vers another jsp (a modal).
```

In the same page, all is good (the jqgrid table is full normally).

Now I want to fill **by the same data** another jqgrid but in another jsp (in my case is a bootstrap modal)  but it  displays anything.

```
var iframeSrc = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/subgridtable_Device_Modal.html?'+ data + '&' + detail ;)
```

I saw the below sample of data when I receive the detail variable in the second page :

{%22A%22:%223%22,%22B%22:%222SC2I%22,%22C%22:%223%22,%22D%22:%222SC2I%22,%22E%22:%2245%22,%22F%22:%22PTS3S40510009246%22,%22G

Also I tried to parse the detail to json data in the second page but no results .

Any one have any idea please.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Why don't you just send your JSON data as a parameter and then parse it again?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a variable as a part of a URL it will always be URL-encoded. When receiving such a parameter most server side programming languages will automatically decode it again for you. When that's not the case, you have to manually decode it. I don't know which server side language you're using though. Or if you use JavaScript to receive that parameter, use decodeURI().